# Updating more than one rows in listview

Tags: android, listview, view

I have a listview which consists of name, text and imageview. If an user named "John" clicks the imageview in the row with user named "Bob", all the rows with name "Bob" inclusive of the currently clicked row should have their imageview changed into another image. I am trying to do this in the following code:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CommentInfo> {


    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_xml, myComments);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        itemView = convertView;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_xml, parent, false);

        }
        final CommentInfo currentComment = myComments.get(position);
        List<View> viewList;
        if(!ht.containsKey(currentComment.userName)){
            viewList = new ArrayList<View>();
            viewList.add(itemView);
            Log.d("username", currentComment.userName);
            Log.d("position", Integer.toString(position));
            ht.put(currentComment.userName, viewList);
        }
        else{
            ((List<View>)ht.get(currentComment.userName)).add(itemView);
            Log.d("username", currentComment.userName);
            Log.d("position", Integer.toString(position));
        }
        final ImageView follows = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.followUserBtn);

        follows.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(follows_flag == 0){
                    follows_flag = 1;
                    followed_person = currentComment.userName;
                    follows.setImageResource(R.drawable.followusersuccesssbtn);
                    List<View> viewList1 = (List<View>) ht.get(currentComment.userName);
                    for(View view : viewList1){
                        ImageView follows_other = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.followUserBtn);
                        follows_other.setImageResource(R.drawable.followusersuccesssbtn);
                    }
                    new StoreFollowed().execute();
                }
                else{
                    follows_flag = 0;
                    followed_person = currentComment.userName;
                    follows.setImageResource(R.drawable.followusericon);
                    List<View> viewList1 = (List<View>) ht.get(currentComment.userName);
                    for(View view : viewList1){
                        ImageView follows_other = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.followUserBtn);
                        follows_other.setImageResource(R.drawable.followusericon);
                    }
                    new DeleteFollowed().execute();
                }
            }
        });            
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I store in hashtable, for each name, list of views. My issue is when John clicks on the imageview in the row with name Bob, all the rows with imageview gets its image changed rather than the rows with only Bob's name. What is the wrong I am doing here? How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First don't keep an association between your data and your view. Android ListView reuses view which means that you will have some views associated each with multiple names. I'm pretty sure your problem comes form this.

You should alway try to only modify your Model Objet and let the list view update the UI.

In you case You could have All your `CommentInfo` objet referencing a `User` with different `CommentInfo` from same user refrencing the `User` object. You can then store you image in this `User` and when you wan't in on click update the user's image and call `notifyDataSetChanged();` so that your list update it's UI.

PS : you might wan't to take a look at [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder). It has nothing to do with you problem but it's a good practice and would increase the smoothness of your list's scrolling.